# SchemaCrawler database plugin should be on the CLASSPATH

Tags: database, postgresql, schemacrawler

I have to get metadata of DB using schemacrawler.

According to https://www.schemacrawler.com/ where I have found example https://github-com.translate.goog/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/schemacrawler-examplecode/src/main/java/com/example/ApiExample.java?_x_tr_sl=en&_x_tr_tl=ru&_x_tr_hl=ru&_x_tr_pto=op,sc , I was trying to run it but got an error `SchemaCrawler database plugin should be on the CLASSPATH for <jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/table_accounts>,  or "SC_WITHOUT_DATABASE_PLUGIN" should be set to the name of the missing plugin  either as an environmental variable or as a Java system property`.

Haven't found any solutions.

My `pom.xml` the same like in example on github.

I tried to add `export SC_WITHOUT_DATABASE_PLUGIN=true` to `.bash_profile` on Mac Os but I had the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `export SC_WITHOUT_DATABASE_PLUGIN=postgresql`, but please add [schemacrawler-postgresql](https://search.maven.org/artifact/us.fatehi/schemacrawler-postgresql) to your Maven build instead, like the [code in the example "pom.xml"](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/schemacrawler-examplecode/pom.xml#L69-L73).

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)